# Easiest way to connect to wifi in python

Tags: python

I want to connect to wifi using python both new and previous connection and also in any os like raspberry pie ,windows etc. can any on tell me how to do that and also I want to connect to wifi with only ssid and password I don't have interface of the wifi networks just ssid and password if required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wireless`:

`pip install wireless`

```
from wireless import Wireless

wire = Wireless()
wire.connect(ssid=name,password=pass)
```

`winwifi`:

`pip install winwifi` (On windows only)

```
import winwifi


name='xxxx'
password='11111'


try:
    winwifi.WinWiFi.connect(name,password)
    print('t')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

or `wifi`:

`pip install wifi`

```
from __future__ import print_function

from wifi import Cell, Scheme

# get all cells from the air
ssids = [cell.ssid for cell in Cell.all('wlan0')]

schemes = list(Scheme.all())

for scheme in schemes:
    ssid = scheme.options.get('wpa-ssid', scheme.options.get('wireless-essid'))
    if ssid in ssids:
        print('Connecting to %s' % ssid)
        scheme.activate()
        break
```

Comment: winwifi will not work in other os and wireless is also not working properly and wifi one is bit tricky